Low budget horror movie about teens in haunted abandoned hospital
This movie is very low budget horror movie. It was about teens in an abandoned hospital that was burned down. Here's what I remember 

probably straight to DVD or made for tv
most likely came out before 2010 and after 1990
a floating clown that had goo that if it got on their skin they would melt
old man who started fire in abandoned hospital, may have been mental hospital 
four or five teens, friends/couples
running and chasing down hallways


Boo (2005)
So I think I've actually seen the movie you're talking about, it has all that you described. This is IMBD's description "handful of college students get trapped in a haunted hospital on Halloween." Here's a link to the trailer 


